# Create notification when application is in background, Android

Tags: android, notifications

***Initial description:***

My application handles some events and do some task related to that event, even if application is in background. I am using receivers.

***Problem description***

I want to show notification when an event starts or end.

***What I did yet***

*I used Notification manager :-*  But I need to show notification on home screen not on notification bar.

*I used App widget :-* But user will not able to notice any changes in information on app widget easily, because this does not do any eye catching effect.

*I used Toast :-* But this having time limitation to show, I want to show notification until user close.

So what should be the option? How can I do my task?

Please refer below image, as what I want

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've explored all the possible options. What you want to achieve is not provided intentionally because it will make for very bad user experience. Imagine a notification (of the kind that you want) popping up when you are looking at an email!

*Attention piracy*

**When your app is in the foreground**, you can do a lot of things.

**When your app is not in the foreground**, there are only two options

- Start an activity: You must do this only if essential (like an incoming phone call activity). If the user deems it more irritating than useful, your app is going down the drain!
- Use the notification manager.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [Alert Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Or you can use run an Activity with the Dialog theme.